# Qt5 from repository with *-devel packages but with no debug symbols on Centos 6.5

Tags: qt, centos, qt5

I am trying to determine a reason for application crashing on Centos 6.5. I have qt5 from EPEL repositories installed complete with all -devel packages, but both gdb and qtcreator seem to think that I do not have debug symbols for Qt libraries... do I need to compile Qt from source or is there a way to make the one from repo work for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking around on freenode I was able to find the answer:

*-debug packages in epel are not installed by default, in fact they are kept separately and must be installed with

```
debuginfo-install <pkg>
```